# Views header with custom summary

Tags: 7, views

Drupal 7 I have a content type called "Question" with a Answered/Not_answered field for editors.
I want to create a view of all questions which has a header of answered and unanswered questions. Something like this:

Answered questions: 10
Unanswered questions: 2

with links to answered and unanswered questions.

Can anyone please help me to create this view?

Many thanks, Alice

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this task you need to create two attachments and tie them to your page.
First attachment should display 'Global: Result summary' result with all answered questions.
Second attachment should display Global: Result summary' result with all unanswered questions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very nice Andrew. You are my hero :) it took me awhile to sort it out but in the end it worked out. Thanks alot!